# How to .focus() using jQuery in a WebKit browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, webkit

the title pretty much explains it. Please note that this is a WebKit-specific issue (at least I have narrowed it down to that, as FireFox presents absolutely no issues). This issue was tested on Chrome 8.0.552.224 and Safari 5.0.2.

I have this HTML structure:

```
<li class="buttonArea"> <span class="buttonHighlight"></span>
    <a href="#" class="button">PRE-ORDER</a>
    <a href="#" class="buttonTag">Got a Coupon Code?</a>
    <span class="buttonBG"></span> 
    <!-- Rainbow background -->
</li>
```

I have created a jQuery function that adds a class to a.button when it is hovered over and when it's being focused. Here's how:

```
$(document).ready(function () { /* ///// start DOM ready ///// */
    /** Big button hover/active effects **/
    $('a.button').hover(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('button-hover');
    });
    $('.button').focus(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('button-active');
        Cufon.replace('.button-active');
    });
}); /* ///// end DOM ready ///// */
```

The button-hover class is added; however, the button-active is not. Even if I remove the Cufon.replace line it doesn't work. Apparently, there is already a ticket on the jQuery site which mentions this WebKit-related issue (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3332), yet I hope that your genius minds can help me!

Comment: which jquery version are you using ??

Comment: This may have been a bug in jQuery 1.3.x (when the ticket you found was filed) but fixed in 1.4.x; using 1.4.4 on Chrome v9.0b works for me with one of the test cases. You should create a test case on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Actually, I am using the Google API to link to the jQuery library: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Well, I tested the jsFiddle outcome on Chrome, and it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/ZFGbL/ .. So again, it's using jQuery 1.4.4 and yet it does not work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, thanks to the help of a good friend of mine and some tweaking, we've found the solution. This is cross-browser compatible and I hope it helps anybody else:

```
$('.button').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('button-hover');
    $(this).mousedown(function () {
        $(this).addClass('button-active');
        Cufon.replace('.button-active');
        $(this).mouseup(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('button-active');
            Cufon.replace('.button');
        });
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('button-hover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well i think you can replace your code  -

```
$('.button').focus(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('button-active');
    Cufon.replace('.button-active');
});
```

by this

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('button-active');
    Cufon.replace('.button-active');
});
```

ie replace focus event with click event and it will work similarly (in chrome too) because click also satisfies your requirement what you expect from focus in your case.

Comment: But click() will add the class once the mouse is pressed AND released. I want the class to be added as soon as the mouse is pressed; and when it is released, the class should be removed. That's why I used focus().